# Is there a readonly partner scope?

Tags: youtube-api

Is there a *partner.readonly* scope?

I'm interested in verifying channel ownership for content owners and am not sure how to do that without the partner scope.

Unfortunately, partner scope provides far more permissions (aka management) than I am interested in getting. It also gives more permissions than creators are willing to consent to.

This is the consent message I would like to modify. I'm only interested in *viewing* info:

> View **and manage** your assets and associated content on YouTube

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no *partner.readonly* scope.

The only scopes that are available at the moment are the ones that can be seen [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#youtubev3) (which you probably already know):

> YouTube Data API, v3
>
> **Scopes**
>
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube Manage your YouTube account
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl   Manage your YouTube account
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly    View your YouTube account
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload  Manage your YouTube videos
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner  View and manage your assets and associated content on YouTube
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner-channel-audit    View private information of your YouTube channel relevant during the audit process with a YouTube partner
>
> ---
>
> YouTube Analytics API, v1
>
> **Scopes**
>
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube Manage your YouTube account
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly    View your YouTube account
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner  View and manage your assets and associated content on YouTube
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics-monetary.readonly  View monetary and non-monetary YouTube Analytics reports for your YouTube content
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly   View YouTube Analytics reports for your YouTube content
>
> ---
>
> YouTube Reporting API, v1
>
> **Scopes**
>
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics-monetary.readonly  View monetary and non-monetary YouTube Analytics reports for your YouTube content
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly   View YouTube Analytics reports for your YouTube content

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping maybe there was a delay in documentation vs functionality.  For example, yt-analytics-monetary.readonly stopped working properly a month ago and was only documented 3/3/17 "monetary.readonly scope does not currently grant access to monetary data in channel reports." -> https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/revision_history

Comment: I get what you mean. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any updates (or any delays) about a *partner.readonly* scope as of the moment. Best advise I can give is to just keep an eye out on that release notes. Cheers!